# Python celery flower no monitor tab (no real-time grohics)

Tags: celery, flower

How I can see a real-time tasks execution?

I'm novice in celery. I'm running celery but don't see a `monitor` tab

`http://127.0.0.1:5555/monitor` returns "page not found"

[image]

Here is how I'm starting it

Celery in the script

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    REDIS_TASKS_BROKER = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
    REDIS_TASKS_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379/1
    app = Celery(main=__name__, broker=REDIS_TASKS_BROKER, backend=REDIS_TASKS_BACKEND)
    worker = app.Worker()
    worker.start()
```

Flower in the terminal (after running a script):

```
celery -A tasks --broker=redis://localhost:6379/0 flower --port=5555
```

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I have the same issue.

Comment: @Unfortunately no

Comment: It was apparently removed in the recent builds (https://github.com/mher/flower/issues/895#issuecomment-786140152) you will have to downgrade to 0.9.4 to get the monitor. I'm able to see the monitor tab after downgrading, but no stats in the charts...

Answer (score 4):

See https://github.com/mher/flower/issues/1107. The monitor tab was deprecated with version v1 and replaced with Prometheus stats. You can either downgrade to v0.9.7 (but beware that it's [not compatible](https://github.com/mher/flower/issues/1029) with Celery v5) or follow [this guide](https://github.com/mher/flower/blob/master/docs/prometheus-integration.rst) to setup the Prometheus integration.